# Identify call is made from front-end or backend for a REST endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-rest

we have a requirement where we want to identify whether the call to a particular endpoint was made from a browser or using say postman/curl etc client to bypass certain security checks.

I thought we can do this by having our logic build on request header say 'User-Agent' or some other header - When calling from browser it is having a value of browser name but with the postman, it is having a different values.

But I want to know, should we have our logic based on the request header. Is it a bad practice to bypass a check based on request headers? Is there some other way this requirement can be fulfilled other the request header

Comment: I'm also intereseted on this. What I was doing so I won't depend entirely the headers which can be fake, was complement it with custom data in the body of the request. They could be fake too, but it will just be redudant. In the future maybe I will also encrypt it (the body data) to make it more difficult to fake both and make them consistent